# Divide or Multiply according to a condition (Improving query)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I'm making a procedure and I want to improve this part.

```
IF(Currency) BEGIN
    SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount / ExchangeRate), 0.00)
    FROM SomeTables
    WHERE SomeConditions
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount * ExchangeRate), 0.00)
    FROM SomeTables
    WHERE SomeConditions
END
```

The thing is if the currency is USD then I have to divide for else I have to multiply. The query involves six tables and many conditions, so it's 25 lines and I don't want to repeat the code inside an IF condition. I'd like to define the operator at the begining and use it in the query (I mean one SELECT). It's only with improving purpose...

Some ideas about how to solve it?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried writing a CASE statement with group by?  I think that would do it in 1 select statement.

Comment: No, I haven't. Could you show me an example please?? I don't know how to use the CASE statement with a SELECT inside

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make use of dynamic queries. Store the operator to be used according to currency in @Operator

```
SET @Query = 'SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount ' +  @Operator  + ' ExchangeRate), 0.00)
FROM SomeTables
WHERE SomeConditions'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @Query
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CASE WHEN THEN`, perhaps like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL (CASE WHEN Currency 
                    THEN SUM(Amount / ExchangeRate)
                    ELSE SUM(Amount * ExchangeRate)
                     END,
        0.00 )  LocalCurrency 
  FROM SomeTables
  etc.
```

This would let you use just one SELECT statement, a useful simplification.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I have a CASE statement after the operator so I would have to duplicate that part. Dynamic queries solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT ISNULL (CASE WHEN Currency = 'USD'
                    THEN SUM(Amount / ExchangeRate)
                    ELSE SUM(Amount * ExchangeRate)
                    END, 0.00 )  TotalAmount 
FROM SomeTables
WHERE SomeConditions
```